# How can I download Java SE 1.5 for Mac OS 10.6

Tags: java, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm searching for a way to download Java 5 for Mac OS 10.6.  Where can I find this?  Sun's site didn't have it for the Mac, and the Mac site only had it for older versions of OS X.

Thanks much.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to run 1.5?

Comment: Not precisely, except to say that Java 6 was causing some problems with Tomcat, when trying to do a port install.  I'm told it has to do with some interfaces that have additional methods . . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this, http://chxor.chxo.com/post/183013153/installing-java-1-5-on-snow-leopard

Unfortunately Apple seems to hate Java, so they're never up-to-date with it...

Comment: Ironically, 10.6 ships with Java 6, making it closer to up-to-date than any previous version...

Comment: The strange thing is that they didn't include previous versions of Java

Answer (score 2):

Try the below steps:

Go to Finder->Utilities->Java and open Java Preferences and select the preferred version.

1. Open terminal and go to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/
2. Type ls -l to list all available Java versions
3. Enter sudo ln -fhsv CurrentJDK

Reference: [Changing Java Version in Mac](http://techmindviews.blogspot.com/2011/10/changing-java-version-mac-1046.html)

Answer (score 0):

moreover the SUN "test your JVM" page (http://www.java.com/en/download/help/5000041300.xml) crashes every browser (firefox 3.0, safari) i tried under osx 10.6